# Mixing sounds using ffmpeg with offsets, itsoffset not working

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to mix three sounds using ffmpeg on android. But I want the last two sounds to mix with first sound on some offset. I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input1 -itsoffset 5 -i input2 -itsoffset 10 -i input3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=3:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 -strict -2 output
```

I gave input2 offset value of 5 seconds, and input3 offset value of 10 seconds. But it just mixes the sounds at the beginning of input1. In short, the itsoffset is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mp3 audio merging with -itsoffset using ffmpeg: no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941140/mp3-audio-merging-with-itsoffset-using-ffmpeg-no-effect)

Comment: @laggingreflex This question was asked before the one you linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1349), the `-itsoffset` parameter only affects the *video* stream (timestamps) but not any audio stream (timestamps).