# mp3 audio merging with -itsoffset using ffmpeg: no effect

Tags: audio, merge, ffmpeg, mp3

I use ffmpeg to merge mp3's in my node server. It works but the offset doesn't have any effect..
I can't see what is wrong then i'd like to get your help :)

```
var command = "ffmpeg -i "+ input1+ " -itsoffset 40 -i " + input2 +" -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 "+ output;

        exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (stdout) console.log(stdout);
            if (stderr) console.log(stderr);

            if (error) {
                console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                response.statusCode = 404;
                response.end();

            } else {
                // Do something
            }

        });
```

I tried it also on my computer just in the terminal and it also works with the same problem..

Thanks,
Itzhak

Comment: `-itsoffset` supports video streams but not audio streams yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixing sounds using ffmpeg with offsets, itsoffset not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906197/mixing-sounds-using-ffmpeg-with-offsets-itsoffset-not-working)

Comment: Thank you! Then if so how can i mix sounds together?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using `itsoffset` you can append a silent audio to the beginning of the audio. Assume we have three audios to be merged each of 10 sec long. So you can append silent audio as follows.

- First audio : No silent audio
- Second audio : Append 10 sec silent audio to the beginning
- Third audio : Append (10 sec) x 2 silent audio to the beginning

There after you can mix all these audios together. To create a silent audio you can use [`aevalsrc`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#aevalsrc) filter with `filter_complex`. Following will work for the above example.

```
ffmpeg -i 0.mp3 -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -filter_complex 
"aevalsrc=0:d=10[s1];
aevalsrc=0:d=20[s2];
[s1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac1];
[s2][2:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[ac2];
[0:a][ac1][ac2]amix=3[aout]" -map [aout] out.mp3
```

Here `[s1]` and `[s2]` are the corresponding silent audio source for second and third input audio streams. Then each silent source will be concatenated with there corresponding audio streams using [`concat`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#concat-1) filter. Finally all concatenated audios will be mixed using [`amix`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#amix) filter.

Else you can try [`amerge`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#amerge) and [`adelay`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) where doc itself has a clear explanation.

Hope this helps!